# Rename a python package after installation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two packages with the same name I need to install. They are not created by me, I just want to use both of them (pyrat, if you are curious)

My questions are: 
- how to best deal with this situation? 
- what if I install one of them, then change the name of the directory (let's say pyrat --> pyrat_whatever) and finally install the other one?

Would that work or there are some issues that I should consider?
I actually did it and it seems working, but I don't know if something can get silently screwed.

### EDIT

One of the modules is this one

- https://github.com/birgander2/PyRAT (it uses distutils during installation)

Comment: For starters, what do you mean by "install"?

Comment: Means that I used the setup.py written by the author.

In one case I use:
`pip3 install path_to_the_setup.py`
in the other simply (being in the folder cloned from github):
`python setup.py install `

Comment: Do you know if the second one is using distutils or setuptools?

Comment: You should be adding all this information to your question BTW. It's very relevant to anyone trying to answer.

Comment: Also, please add in the output of `pip`. It will give a clue as to what needs to be renamed.

Comment: The second one uses distutils. 
I updated a bit the post. Unfortunately I'm not sure I can post the pip output